Flutter BoxFix.cover does not cover but stretch the video
 SizedBox(
                height: context.height,
                width: context.width,
                child: FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    child: SizedBox(
                        height: context.height,
                        width: context.width,
                        child: VideoPlayer(videoC.value!))),

I have this and it does not fit the box but just squeeze the video into fit in that height and width. How can I make it cover the Sizedbox?

its no point in using FittedBox if both parent and child of it have the same size, are you sure you pasted the correct code?

Yeah that is what I have. if I don't have one of them then it did not work

chek the below answer: here FittedBox expands to the available space while its child (with VideoPlayer) takes the size of the asset you are showing - this is the case where FittedBox can scale its child

Does this work for you with the video_player plugin?
SizedBox.expand(
  child: FittedBox(
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    child: ListenableBuilder(
      listenable: _videoController,
      builder: (context, _) => SizedBox(
        width: _videoController.value.size?.width ?? 0,
        height: _videoController.value.size?.height ?? 0,
        child: VideoPlayer(_videoController),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),


SizedBox(
height: context.height,
width: context.width,
child: FittedBox(
fit: BoxFit.cover,
child: SizedBox(
height: videoC.value!.value.size.height,
width: videoC.value!.value.size.width,
child: VideoPlayer(videoC.value!),
),
),
),
this worked! thanks !!
